# How to create references in Entity Framework when the database schema does not have them?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I have a database schema which I cannot alter, and which has tables that reference each other without declaring an explicit foreign key relationship.  For example:

```
create table Foo (
  Id int identity not null primary key, 
  X int
)

create table Bar (
  Id int identity not null primary key, 
  FooId int, -- as if "references Foo(Id)"
  Y int
)
```

I would like to access these tables via EntityFramework (4.0 or 4.1).  Is it possible to have EF treat `FooId` as it were a foreign key referencing the table `Foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the Microsoft EF forum, and it was answered there; see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d4db23e4-ab0d-4d10-bd52-123cb2b641e1

In short I did not realize how much one can edit the associations after creating them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  For references about mapping using DB, Model, or Code First, I would suggest the [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/).

Comment: Thanks.  I've taken a look at the blog and it's not clear where they address my question.  Are there any posts that are particularly worth looking at in order to accomplish what I described in my question?

Comment: I'm sorry, now that I've looked more closely at these, I see that these were only really a "getting started" guide. EF is currently moving too fact for anyone to pin down (apparently) and there are few references.  I think I managed to get a solution in my situation (Code First w/fluent mapping) with BoL and a little experimentation.  I'll see if I can work up a quick example for you.

Comment: That would be great.  Even some vague pointers would be useful.  Thanks.